# External monitor has dark banding around colors

Tags: display, colors, external-display

I'm not sure how to describe this phenomenon properly. However, my new Asus VX24AH shows dark borders/banding around coloured boxes or text. It is plugged into a Late 2013 Retina MacBook Pro using HDMI.

[image: IMG:]  
[image: IMG:]
<sup>Image 1: Asus VX24AH, Image 2: MacBook Retina built-in monitor</sup>

As you can see, the banding doesn't occur on the built-in display.

What causes the border issue on the external display and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Monitors have various input processing steps where they "improve" the image. To turn them all off you can almost always enable a "game mode" in the menu of the screen - the one you control with buttons on the monitor. The game mode is called that way because disabling all that processing improves display latency, which is good for gaming.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't fix this particular issue

Comment: @DanielGalletta According to ASUS (https://www.asus.com/Monitors/VX24AH/), they still do post processing in game mode. The mode that doesn't do the increased contrast on edges might be sRGB.

Comment: I've tried all the modes and none of them solve the problem